# Which datasets can I use to train a medical speech recognition system?

Tags: computational-linguistics, speech-recognition, datasets

So far I found:

- [ezDI Medical Dictation Dataset](https://ezdi-datasets.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/ezDI-Medical-Dictation-Dataset.zip) (16h)
- https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/paultimothymooney/medical-speech-transcription-and-intent (8h)

Which other datasets can I use to train a medical speech recognition system?

Comment: Any answers or comments are welcome.

Comment: I am still interested in this question.